# ASP.NET Ajax: 'PageMethods is undefined' script error on production server (works on localhost)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods

In a javascript file I'm calling an ASP.NET Ajax PageMethod (ASP.NET 3.5), correctly defined in the page class a static method using the WebMethod attribute. This **works on my development machine**, but on the production server the **PageMethod object is undefined** when my javascript function is called (clicking a button).

Some debugging info:

- Error on Firefox and Internet Explorer
- According to Firebug's network tab all external resources are correctly loaded
- I'm using jQuery on the same page
- The application is deployed using a Web Deployment project

Any idea what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem after having written the question. I'm doing a [dirty trick in order to avoid copying the aspx placeholder files (Web Deployment Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424230/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-aspx-placeholder-files-in-a-asp-net-web-deployment-p) to the server: in IIS I've unchecked the .aspx ISAPI extension option "Verify that file exists".

That seems to be a problem for ASP.NET Ajax. So I created an empty aspx placeholder file and ... now it's working on the production server too. I'll put a warning sign on the question/answer I linked above.